# безопасна ли команда redis-cli flushall?

Tags: база-данных, redis

Есть проблема - страница грузится очень долго. Эта проблема только в production.

Посоветовали сделать `redis-cli flushall`.

Безопасна ли эта команда в production?
После команды надо будет пересоздать базу?
Перед командой надо сделать бэкап?

Прошу прощения, с редис не работал до этого.

Comment: "Машина не едет. Мне посоветовали заменить свечу зажигания. Это безопасно?" Когда реально у машины может быть неисправен двигатель, педаль газа или замок зажигания, может не быть бензина, не быть колёс.

Comment: @D-side, Или она просто не заведена o_O.

Comment: могли бы подсказать безопасна ли эта команда в production? т.е. удаление ключей можно делать в prod? спасибо

Comment: Мы не имеем ни малейшего представления, как Redis используется в вашем продукте и как на него повлияет удаление абсолютно всех данных из Redis. Если не знаете и вы, значит не знает никто. Знаю, вывод неутешительный.